# Wrong GeoJson multipolygon from the island Sylt

Tags: geojson, here-api

Do you have an idea how we can get the GeoJson multipolygon from the whole island of Sylt in HERE and not just a part of it?

If we make the query about HERE-API we get this GeoJson which reflects this multipolygon: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/details.html?osmtype=R&osmid=1147134&class=boundary
[Wrong Multipolygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay8Uf.png)

But what we actually need is the GeoJson of the entire island of Sylt, which should look like this: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/details.html?osmtype=R&osmid=1576925&class=place
[Expected Multipolygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzvsr.png)

Comment: can you post the API call you're making ?

Comment: @ShrutiKuber We use this query: https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=Sylt&additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,country&apiKey=YOUR_KEY&gen=9

Answer (score 0):

So, Instead of having additional data as `IncludeShapeLevel, country` , you should change it to `IncludeShapeLevel, county`. You will get the boundary of the complete island of Sylt. You are getting half a boundary as the match level was city.

Comment: With county we don't get Sylt as whole island, because the `county` is "Nordfriesland". This is the result with county: https://ibb.co/PTMjDgC

Comment: I see. I will file a ticket for this and get back to you!

Comment: Are there any news yet?

Comment: Are there any news? @ShrutiKuber